# Tag merge request: log and logging

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge

The following tags need merging together:

- [log](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/log)
- [logging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/logging)

These tags are both being used for questions about logging.